# Proving the uniform convergence of $ f_n (x) = \sin(\frac{1}{n})\cos(x)$

Tags: uniform-convergence

I need to find the pointwise limit and determine the uniform convergence of the sequence of functions $ f_n (x) = \sin(\frac{1}{n})\cos(x)$ where $f$ maps from reals to reals.

I got the pointwise limit to be $0$, but I am unsure how to prove the uniform convergence. I believe it starts with bounding this function -- upper bound is $1$ and lower bound is $-1$. I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$|\sin(x)| \leqslant |x|$$
So what can you say about
$$||f_n-0||_u=\sup_x\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\cos(x)\right|\text{ ?}$$

Comment: What do the double absolute value and subscript u represent?

Comment: @kt046172 It's the uniform norm. How do you define the uniform convergence?

Comment: Let $(E,d) , (E', d')$ be metric spaces. If given any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a positive integer $N$ such that $d'(f(p), f_n(p))<\epsilon$ whenever $ n > N $ for all $ p \in E $

Comment: @kt046172 I guess in your case both of the metric spaces are $\mathbb{R}$ with the euclidian metric. In that case, $|\sin(1/n)\cos(x)-0|\leqslant \frac{|\cos(x)|}{n}$. Can you continue?

Comment: Sorry, where does the $\frac{cos(X)}{n} come from? I'm lost

Comment: @kt046172 We have that $|\sin(1/n)| \leqslant |1/n|=1/n$.

Comment: So in proving uniform convergence, we can assert that as this will approach 0 as n approaches infinity and thus will work for any epsilon?

Comment: @kt046172 What do you mean? To prove that it converges uniformly, you can note that $|\cos(x)|\leqslant 1$, which means that $|f_n(x)|\leqslant \frac{1}{n}$ for all $x$. This means that you can take $N=\text{floor}(1/\epsilon)+1$.